# Search neighboring points using k-d trees

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, binary-search-tree

I have a bunch of coordinates contained in three `numpy` arrays: `xarr`, `yarr` and `zarr` (corresponding positions in each array belong to the same point - i.e the first point is at `xarr[0]`, `yarr[0]`, `zarr[0]`). Given another point in space at `P(x,y,z)` I would like to find all the points that are within a distance *r* of `P(x,y,z)`.

My current (and very inefficient) method of doing this is to simply iterate through and calculate the distance to each point and see if it is within *r* of `P(x,y,z)`.

However, I'd like to use SciPy's k-d tree algorithm to do this, but I'm not really sure how to start implementing it (I'm very new to Python). I'd really appreciate it if someone could briefly outline some code that demonstrates *how to set up* a k-d tree given data in the format I've got.

I know of [SciPy documentation of its k-d tree implementation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.KDTree.html#scipy.spatial.KDTree), 
I've looked over it but I'm still confused on how to create the tree given the data in the format I have (`np.mgrid` and `ravel()` were called and I don't quite understand why).

Thanks!

Comment: If I understand correctly, you have a *single* Nx3 array of points, and for each point in that array you want to count the number of other points that fall within some radius of it?

Comment: @ali_m They have 3 separate arrays, one for each coordinate, and they want to find, among the points so described, the points that are close to a new point.

Comment: I don't know if this is useful to this particular question, I'm not big on k-d trees (although I probably should), but I've found this to be a useful library: https://networkx.github.io/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Omitting the imports... I don't have your data, so I have to fake some...

```
In [40]: x = np.random.random(100)
In [41]: y = np.random.random(100)    
In [42]: z = np.random.random(100)    
In [43]: p = np.random.random(3)    
In [44]: p
Out[44]: array([ 0.60515083,  0.39263392,  0.36129813])
```

namely three arrays of coordinates and a point for which I will search the neighbors.

---

Next, let's see how can I construct an array with as many rows as the different data points and three colunms...

```
In [45]: np.vstack((x,y,z)).T.shape
Out[45]: (100, 3)
```

well, it is correct.

---

We build the k-d tree using `KDTree` from `scipy.spatial`

```
In [46]: tree = KDTree(np.vstack((x,y,z)).T)
```

and then we use one of the methods of the tree, the aptly-named `.query_ball_point()`, to find the indices of the points near to `p`

```
In [47]: indices = tree.query_ball_point(p, 0.33)
```

where I've used, arbitrarily, a radius equal to 1/3.

---

Eventually we want to see these neighbors, so I'll use the `.data` attribute of the tree and the indices that I've just computed like this

```
In [48]: tree.data[indices]
Out[48]: 
array([[ 0.4117843 ,  0.21440852,  0.3352732 ],
       [ 0.48921727,  0.13855976,  0.43331816],
       [ 0.71598133,  0.32270361,  0.20292187],
       [ 0.71761991,  0.27309708,  0.12670474],
       [ 0.6282775 ,  0.13752325,  0.4143872 ],
       [ 0.55995847,  0.31302848,  0.2780926 ],
       [ 0.75896359,  0.16043536,  0.33530071],
       [ 0.81138529,  0.64635994,  0.33819097],
       [ 0.43537193,  0.5353203 ,  0.52095431],
       [ 0.66996807,  0.48346547,  0.52761835],
       [ 0.69426851,  0.24725511,  0.57650329],
       [ 0.5350322 ,  0.23155768,  0.62545958],
       [ 0.51228139,  0.38078056,  0.61246054]])
```

and that's all...

Comment: This was great! Thank you so much, it's exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an explanation of the example provided in the scipy docs :

```
from scipy import spatial
x, y = np.mgrid[0:4, 0:4]
```

`np.mgrid` creates a mesh grid x,y from 0 to 4. Since you already have your x,y,z coordinates, you are going to skip this step.

```
points = zip(x.ravel(), y.ravel())
points = zip(xarr.ravel(), yarr.ravel(), zarr.ravel()) #in your case
points = zip(xarr, yarr, zarr) # if x,y,z are already 1-d
```

`zip` creates a list of tuples containing each x,y point pair (associate together the coordinates for each point). `ravel` flattens the x, y mesh grid (converts a n-d array to 1-d) so that `zip` can be used. In your case you will only use `ravel` if `xarr`, `yarr`, `zarr` are not already 1-d.

```
tree = spatial.KDTree(points)
```

Create index the points to provide rapid neighbour look up.

```
tree.query_ball_point([2, 0], 1)
```

Look up points within `r=1` of the point `[2,0]`

Hope this helps.